# Having trouble finding error in my assembly code

Tags: debugging, assembly, compiler-construction, machine-code, 68000

I am a beginner when it comes to assembly language.  I am using "easy 68k editor/assembler" to write 68k assembly code that asks the user for 2 values, then sum them up together and display it.  The problem is that my code keeps getting halted and I am not sure how to troubleshoot/debug this problem.

Can anyone help me figure out how to track down the error?  I will be grateful.  Thank you in advance.

```
*-----------------------------------------------------------
* Program    : Sum of Two Numbers
* Written by : Me
* Date       : July 15, 2012
* Description: This program will read in 2 numbers the user
*inputs and find the sum.
*-----------------------------------------------------------

    org     $8000

    START       movea.l #MSG1, A3
                trap    #3
                clr.w   D2
                JSR     Loop
                trap    #2
                move.w  d2, d4
                movea.l #msg2, a3
                trap    #3
                clr.w   d2
                jsr     loop
                trap    #2
                movea.l #msg3, A3
                trap    #3
                add.w   d4, d2
                JSR     DISP
                trap    #2
                trap    #9
    LOOP        trap    #0
                trap    #1
                cmp.b   #$0D, D1
                BEQ     BREAK
                and.b   #$0F, d1
                mulu    #10, d2
                add.w   d1, d2
                jmp     loop
    Break       rts
    DISP        clr.b   d3
    DISDIV      divu    #10, D2
                move.b  #16, d5
                ror.l   d5, d2
                or.b    #$30, d2
                move.b  d2, -(A7)
                addq    #1, d3
                clr.w   d2
                ror.l   d5, d2
                bne     DISDIV
    DISDIG      move.b  (a7)+, D1
                trap    #1
                subq.b  #1, D3
                bne     DISDIG
                rts
                org     $8100
    MSG1        DC.B    'Please enter the first of two numbers (two digits) ', 0
    MSG2        DC.B    'Please enter the second of two numbers (two digits) ', 0
    MSG3        DC.B    'The sum of the two 2 digit numbers you entered is ', 0
                end     start
```

Comment: If there is another forum i can be better off posting this in, please let me know.  Thank You

Comment: Can't step through it in a 68000 simulator and see where it fails?

Comment: I know where it fails. i just dont know why.  Its a trap exception where i call my first trap #3.

Comment: im still playing around with it, ill post edited code.

Comment: If you know where it fails, why not say so in the question? The more information you provide the more likely somebody will be able to help.

Comment: What is `trap #3` supposed to do?  What are its parameters?  Better yet, post a link to the API the code is using so we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the traps you are using are not those used by Easy68K. Look [here](http://www.easy68k.com/QuickStart/TrapTasks.htm) for the traps used by Easy68K.

The function of the trap instructions is *not* defined by the 68K assembly language, but rather assigned by the operation system (if the OS makes use of the traps at all, some just ignore them). If you execute a trap instruction the 68000 just executes the code the trap vector points to. There is no "buildin" function assigned to any trap.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should start with:

```
LEA    MSG1, A1
MOVE.B #14, D0
TRAP   #15
```

This will display the first message to the user.  Check out the [EASy68K home page](http://www.easy68k.com) for more information on invoking I/O traps.